# How do figure out problem in logcat in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

I have a bug problem where my app closes whenever it launches and I have read that I should look in my logcat to identify problem but I don't know how do I read the logcat and understand how to solve the problems. These are all the errors I'm getting in my logcat

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                

Process: com.mydomain.calculator, PID: 6294
                                                                                            

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain.calculator/com.mydomain.calculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

This is the only androidruntime error I'm getting. I'm not sure how to solve it can someone help

Answer (score 0):

I think your theme already has a toolbar and in your layout you are trying to use another one. So, remove the default toolbar that comes within your theme. In your themes.xml, change parent to NoActionBar like below.

```
<style name="<app theme name>" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```